# p tabView Error in primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

When I include another page in `home.xhtml` page I got below error

```
Mar 03, 2014 5:04:20 PM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/views/home.xhtml]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteWriter.write(CoyoteWriter.java:184)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.write(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:123)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlResponseWriter.write(HtmlResponseWriter.java:662)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeTabHeader(TabViewRenderer.java:232)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeHeaders(TabViewRenderer.java:182)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeMarkup(TabViewRenderer.java:132)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeEnd(TabViewRenderer.java:72)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:879)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1650)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:164)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:849)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1643)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1646)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:389)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:127)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:135)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Mar 03, 2014 5:04:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/MySqlMavenJSF] threw exception [null] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteWriter.write(CoyoteWriter.java:184)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.write(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:123)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlResponseWriter.write(HtmlResponseWriter.java:662)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeTabHeader(TabViewRenderer.java:232)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeHeaders(TabViewRenderer.java:182)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeMarkup(TabViewRenderer.java:132)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabViewRenderer.encodeEnd(TabViewRenderer.java:72)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:879)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1650)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:164)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:849)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1643)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1646)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:389)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:127)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:135)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:309)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

**home.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

   <f:view>
    <h:head>
        <title>Home</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:form id="homeForm">
        <p:tabView id="homeTabViewId">
            <p:tab id="tab1">
                <ui:include src="/views/lookup.xhtml"></ui:include>
            </p:tab>
        </p:tabView>
    </h:form>
   </f:view>

</html>
```

Comment: Reviewed your question and said it's NPE so you have to debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`title` attribute is missed in `p:tab` component.

```
<p:tab id="tab1" title="LookUp Master And Details ">
    <ui:include src="/views/lookup.xhtml"></ui:include>
</p:tab>
```